# How to get child nodes in a <td> in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, dom-selection

I'm trying to get the child nodes from a table, multiply that and show that on a input field. I have tried using textContext but it only returns first value not the later ones.

My Javascript code is:

```
function add() {
  console.log("this is working")
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("id_quantity").value);
  console.log(x, "value of x");
  var y = document.getElementById("quantity").textContent;
  document.getElementById("id_quantity_p1").value = x * y;
```

[image]

This is my HTML markup:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-12">
    <form method="post" id="MaterialRequestForm" data-kit-url="{% url 'employee:ajax_load_kit' %}"  onkeyup="add()"
                  data-product-url="{% url 'employee:ajax_load_product' %}"
                  novalidate>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form|crispy }}


                <button type="submit">Save</button>
                <div id="products-table" class="col-md-12 col-sm-8 col-12 product-table-ajax">

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

And This is my table's HTML code:

```
{% for product in products %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ product.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.product_name }}</td>
        {% for i in quantities %}
            {% if forloop.counter == forloop.parentloop.counter %}
                <td id="quantity">{{ i }}</td>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

    {% endfor %}
```

In this `<td id-"quantity"` returns multiple values and I want first two of it.

They are in django HTML template

In this I want to enter quantity and I want that it should get multiplied by content Std Qty in column and get filled in "quantity p1", "quantity p2", "quantity p3". eg. quantity*stdQty[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1T4L.png)=quantityP1, quantity*stdQty[2]=quantityP2, quantity*stdQty[3]=quantityP3 etc. For that I need specific elements in my `<td>`. Please help!

Comment: the question is incomplete?

Comment: If you can share jsFiddle or so, that will be pretty helpful.

Comment: no question is complete, I want to get what is inside <td> tags using javascript, thats it.

Comment: @chirag your question is not clear elaborate it but as per my understanding I think you are trying to implement something on change in input field it should automatically fill the other input field and for that you have to apply onchange function in your input field where you wants to give data. Simultaneously in onchange function you update the other input field.

Comment: no question is complete, I want to get what is inside <td> tags using javascript, thats it. I need what is inside the <td> tag first

Comment: please give your online editor link or your code so that we can check.

Comment: @MukeshBurnwalMike I can't because its a django template HTML and it is depending on multiple HTML file to formulate

Comment: For this example, the Django isn't important. Instead, consider including an example of what the output HTML would look like.

Comment: I've edited my question, It hope its more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

I did that with a different way:
I attached different ID's with the form and then instead of fetching child of  I assigned different ID's to all the  and then used getElementByID:

```
{% for product in products %}
<tr>
        <td>{{ product.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.product_name }}</td>
        {% for i in quantities %}
            {% if forloop.counter == forloop.parentloop.counter %}
                <td id="q{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ i }}</td>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

    {% endfor %}

    </tr>
```

And then changed my js accordingly:

```
  function add() {
  console.log("this is working")
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("id_quantity").value);
  console.log(x, "value of x");
  var y =document.getElementById("q1").textContent;
  var y1 =document.getElementById("q2").textContent;
  var y2 =document.getElementById("q3").textContent;
  var y3 =document.getElementById("q4").textContent;
  var y4 =document.getElementById("q5").textContent;
  document.getElementById("id_quantity_p1").value = x * y;
  document.getElementById("id_quantity_p2").value = x * y1;
  document.getElementById("id_quantity_p3").value = x * y2;
  document.getElementById("id_quantity_p4").value = x * y3;
  document.getElementById("id_quantity_p5").value = x * y4;
```

Answer (score 0):

It will obviously only give you back the first one due to the fact that you are using a body.getElementById function, which only returns the very first element with the said id you look for.

For getting all the values you need, I suggest you could instead remake "id_quantity" into a class instead.

With that being done, use body.getElementsByClassName instead, write a loop that stores the data from every node of "id_quantity" and loop it back into the fields where you multiply them.

Here's a very quick example of what I mean

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="color-div">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>2</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="input">5</td>
            <td class="output"></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td class="input">7</td>
            <td class="output"></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td class="input">10</td>
            <td class="output"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Javasript:

```
  let arr = [];

  const $input = document.getElementsByClassName("input");
  const $output = document.getElementsByClassName("output");

  for (let i = 0; i < $input.length; i += 1) {
    arr.push($input[i].innerHTML);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < $output.length; i += 1) {
    $output[i].innerHTML = arr[i] * 5;
  }
```